# Is there any way to use a NuGet package with NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm, nuget

I am working on an Angular 4 application created using the Angular CLI. As such, it uses NPM for package management and building. We would like to continue to use NPM for this.

However, there is a JavaScript package hosted on an internal NuGet server that I would like to add to the project. I've been searching for a way to do this, but so far have come up empty-handed. Is there any way to incorporate this NuGet package into the NPM install and build?